# Loading dialog when form is filled and submitted

Tags: javascript, ajax, validation, dialog

I would like to run a dialog message only when the form is completely filled and I can't manage to make it work, could be nice if someone could explain me what I did wrong.

See following code - Javascript:

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
           $('form').on("submit",function() {
            $('#wrapper').dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Welcome'
            });
            $('#myBtn').click(function() {
                $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
            }); }
     });
```

Dialog:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Welcome!<br />
    You are now logged in.</p>
  </div>
```

Form:

```
<form>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required="required">
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
<button type="submit" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Login</button>
</form>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The solution requires ajax, you have ajax as a tag but there is not ajax in the code

Answer (score 0):

For starters the javascript contains an error, the .on("submit" function is missing it's closing parentheses. But, that's really not the problem here.

**In your javascript right now you're saying the following:**

1. When the document has loaded
2. Listen for a form submit
3. When the form is submitted
4. Initiate a dialog using the element with id "wrapper"
5. The initiated dialog should not be open when loaded
6. Set the dialog title to "Welcome"
7. Listen for a click on the button with id "myBtn"
8. When the button is clicked open the dialog with id "wrapper"

When you read that logic you can see that we're going to show the information in the "wrapper" div until the form was submitted. Because it's only after the form submission that we actually tell the browser that this div should be a dialog.

You also need to prevent the forms default submit behaviour, otherwise you're going to reload the page och send the user somewhere else.
I'd recommend using this code instead and to make your own list explaining it's logic:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Welcome'
  });
    
  $('form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#wrapper').dialog('open');
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply.
How can I prevent the forms default submit behaviour? This is what the e.preventDefault();